# jQuery - How to target nested elements?

Tags: jquery, html, nested

I am attempting to target ids with jquery.  Unfortunately, they are nested deep into divs and my jquery won't work.  As an example, how would I target:

```
id="beds"
```

within

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="page">
    <form>
        <select class="customSelect_beds" id="beds">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#beds').change(multiply);
$('#baths').change(multiply);
$('#frequency').change(multiply);

function multiply() {
    var beds = parseFloat($('#beds').val()),
        baths = parseFloat($('#baths').val()),
        baselight = 54,
        bedmodlight = (beds * 12),
        bathmodlight = (baths * 6),
        basereg = 54,
        bedmodreg = (beds * 18),
        bathmodreg = (baths * 12),
        basedeep = 72,
        bedmoddeep = (beds * 24),
        bathmoddeep = (baths * 18),
        discount = $('#frequency').val(),
        light_cleaning = Math.ceil((baselight + bedmodlight + bathmodlight) * discount),
        regular_cleaning = Math.ceil((basereg + bedmodreg + bathmodreg) * discount),
        deep_cleaning = Math.ceil((basedeep + bedmoddeep + bathmoddeep) * discount);

    $('#total_light').text((light_cleaning) || "--");
    $('#total_regular').text((regular_cleaning) || "--");
    $('#total_deep').text((deep_cleaning) || "--");
};
```

});
I can't seem to find this info anywhere (though I am still looking).  Any tips?

EDIT - Code added and truncated for space.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting downvoted for not knowing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an id you can use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#beds')
```

Comment: Well, my original method was actually correct.  My html had a typo in one of the ids used in the script.  So this will work with deeply nested elements. Sorry to doubt you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#content').find('#beds');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working either using the code after this

Comment: $('#content').find('#beds').change(multiply);

Comment: So nothing happens? Are you getting any console errors, have you included jQuery to the html, what happens?

Comment: No console errors in Chrome and I've tried moving the jQuery to the html as well.  I know it's a targeting issue.  I'm not that great with jquery and I'm simply trying to figure out exactly how to target it properly.  The code was working fine when I tested it at the top levels in jsFiddle as well.  As soon as I nested it into elements it stopped working.

Comment: The targeting is correct `$('#beds')` could you show the whole code in jsfiddle so i could see what the problem is

Comment: Best part of all, those #total ids at the bottom that show the result are nested even deeper into the tree too.  I know once I figure the easier ones out I can get the rest.  I'm still digging through Google as we speak.

Comment: It doesn't matter how deep they are nested, is there any chance you have duplicate ids?

Comment: Yea of course, here it is working just fine without any nesting http://jsfiddle.net/NUGAw/ , and here it is not working with nested elements http://jsfiddle.net/E2bex/

Comment: Ty for fiddle i'll try out some things

Comment: Wow.  I just did a find on the document to search for the ids to make sure they weren't duplicated and I found a typo in one of the id used for this script.  Once I changed it, it worked fine.  So I guess thanks!  Talking it out helped.  Now it's time to sleep.

Comment: Yea just found it too :p `frquency`